# How to execute commands from an attached console

Tags: c++, winapi, c++17, windows-console

I'm coding a WinAPI GUI program that needs calling *ftp* and possibly other console programs while getting their console output to act accordingly *ie. waiting for ftp to complete execution before reading all its output wouldn't do.*

My current approach is calling `CreateProcess()` to create a *cmd.exe* process potentially hiding the ugly console window, `AttachConsole()` to make it my own, `GetStdHandle()` to get input and output handles, `SetConsoleCursorPosition()` to the end of the *console buffer*, and `WriteConsole()` with commands such as *ftp\n* or *dir\n*. Yet this commands are written but not executed. However, I can manually use the same console ( using `CreateProcess()` with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag ) to type *ftp* press enter and get it executed.

Previous approaches involved:

1. Calling *ftp* directly with `CreateProcess()` and redirected inputs/outputs.

   > Couldn't get *ftp* output until the `CreateProcess()` process had already ended.
2. Using `system()`.

   > Was advised against its usage before getting any output.

My current stripped down code:

```
// Next two structures might be a bit misleading, they were used for the 1. previous
// approach
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION)); 
STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security;
security.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
security.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
security.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
CreateProcess( NULL, "cmd", &security, &security, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS |
 CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo); 
uint32_t pidConsole = piProcInfo.dwProcessId;
while ( ! AttachConsole(pidConsole) ){};
HANDLE myConsoleIn, myConsoleOut;
myConsoleIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
myConsoleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
Sleep(100);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO myConsoleCursorInformation = {};
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(myConsoleOut,&myConsoleCursorInformation);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(myConsoleOut,myConsoleCursorInformation.dwSize);
CHAR myConsoleBuffer[200]="dir\n";
DWORD myConsoleProcessed;
WriteConsole( myConsoleOut, myConsoleBuffer, 4, &myConsoleProcessed, NULL);
```

**How can I get a command written in the console to execute?** Is there an alternative to my attempt of ending commands with a trailing `\n` *ie. using* `WriteConsole()` *with a dir\n or ftp\n argument.*

I thought about sending a keypress to the process in question after typing the desired command. Yet the created console needs not only to manually press the enter key but also having *dir*, *ftp* or whatever command to be manually typed.

Please feel free to point out any missing information !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get a command written in the console to execute? Is there an
>   alternative to my attempt of ending commands with a trailing \n ie.
>   using WriteConsole() with a dir\n or ftp\n argument.

Try the following code to see if it works:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

const wchar_t *cmdPath = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
wchar_t *cmdArgs = (wchar_t *)L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /k dir";

BOOL result = CreateProcess(cmdPath, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
if (!result)
{
    std::cout << "Create Process failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

> /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>             This is useful for testing, to examine variables

Use /C if you want "Run Command and then terminate".

**Update:** **Complete code for communicating with a child process(cmd.exe) using pipes.**

```
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

#define BUFSIZE 1024

void ErrorExit(LPCTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}

void ReadFromPipe(void)
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD bytesAvail = 0;
        if (!PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvail, NULL)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to call PeekNamedPipe" << std::endl;
        }
        if (bytesAvail) {
            DWORD n;
            BOOL success = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &n, NULL);
            if (!success || n == 0) {
            }
            bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf,n, &dwWritten, NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}

void WriteToPipe(void)
{
    DWORD dwWritten;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    CHAR buf[] = "dir\n";

    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, buf, sizeof(buf)-1, &dwWritten, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation"));

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));


    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    TCHAR cmdPath[] = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");

    BOOL result = CreateProcess(cmdPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout << "Create Process failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        ReadFromPipe();

        WriteToPipe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I do get whatever command I write down with /k executed, yet the console renders useless immediately afterwards. I've still got the same problem without solution. Suppose I run "cmd /k ftp". I can't send more commands to the ftp program running as needed!

Comment: @JuanManuelLópezManzano You can via the pipe to communicate with the created process. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) is an example you can reference.

Comment: Han That's my previous attempt "1.". Output doesn't seem to be available until the created console closes. I need to act upon output.

Comment: @JuanManuelLópezManzano Sorry for late. I update my answer by adding the complete code that works for me. You can have a check.

Comment: Couldn't make it work yet. I see you're not using WinAPI to create a GUI. Do printf calls work in a WinAPI GUI? I kind of got close to my goal by using a ConPTY approach, but listening to the pipe got me an unknown codified text I could't parse. Have you got any WinAPI working examples? I appreciate your help, thank you.